# CodeIgniter version 3.1.11 - While importing CSV special character issue

Tags: php, csv, codeigniter

While importing **CSV** data, in one of my **CSV** file cell has value in **" "** **double quotes**

**Example** the cell value is ->  my name is **"omkar"**

and this **double quotes** disturb my **sql query**

I tried below solution in codeigniter.

**$db = get_instance()->db->conn_id;** for **mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $cellValue)**

but it returns this error

**Message:mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given**

Comment: try and see what is coming from print_r($cellValue). It should show array not string according to your error message

Comment: yes, **$db** is **array** and **$cellValue** is **string** but the same thing working in php very well, in function  **mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $cellValue)** must have to pass database instance.

Comment: I've never used CodeIgniter but the [tutorial](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/tutorial/create_news_items.html#model) uses something like `$this->db->insert()`. It'd be shocking that a well-known framework doesn't handle SQL injection automatically.

Comment: @omkar I am asking for $cellValue, can you print and share the value

Comment: Where is your code you are using to read in the CSV File? Have you taken a look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php using fgetcsv takes care of all of that.